# How to store defined attributes that will be used in an Hstore in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

One of the attributes on my Template model is called settings and is an HSTORE type.

I have the following right now:

```
# Template model
store_accessor :settings, :width, :height,
                          :number_of_allowed_images, :is_ecommerce


# View
<%= f.fields_for :settings do |s| %>
  <%= f.text_field :width %>
  <%= f.text_field :height %>
  <%= f.check_box :is_ecommerce %>
<%= end %>

# Controller

params.require(:template).permit(:name, settings: [:width, :height, :number_of_allowed_images, :is_ecommerce])
```

I have just shown those 4 settings attributes, but I have around 80. Some of those attributes have to be treated as a text_field, but others are boolean (is_ecommerce) for example.

Right now I am writing 'statically' the attributes in both the model, view and controller, but I am looking for a way that I can manage (add/remove/delete) the attributes that are available for the settings, taking into account that not all the attributes are of the same type, and that ideally I want some of them to have a default value (is_ecommerce should be false by default).

How do you do these when dealing with HSTORE attributes?

Comment: `hstore` can only contain `text` values and doesn't support defaults.

It sounds like you should be modelling this as a relation or a couple of relations, not with `hstore`. The whole point of `hstore` is that it's useful when you don't know the attributes in advance.

If you do need dynamic attributes, but want to impose typing, you may want to look at storing `json` not `hstore` as it supports basic data typing. In newer PostgreSQL versions (9.3 and 9.4) there's more and more support for indexing and querying json.

Comment: Craig Ringer thanks for the comment. I was suggested to use hstore because I have a table with lots of attributes. Right now I just have 10, but more will be added.